# Compatibility problem when resizing an image inside css grid layout

Tags: html, css-grid

Here my page layout, the image should vertically fit into the first row:

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="header" class="vcenter">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" id="logo">
  </div>
  <div id="e1"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: #001018;
}

#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header" 
        "e1";
    gap: 20px;
}

#header { grid-area: header; }

#e1 { grid-area: e1; }

#main > div {
    background-color: #334455;
    padding: 5px;
}

#logo {
    max-width: auto;
    max-height: 80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.vcenter {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Firefox successfully centers the image after resizing but Chrome shifts the image down, like so:

[image]

Is there a simple way to make this compatible in both browsers with minimal changes to the css/html, keeping the current grid layout?

Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/tfoller/pnmjvq58/32/

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough height. Add `height: 100%` to `#logo`. Like that:

```
#logo {
    ...
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will work in both browsers.